# Shell script: unexpected `('

Tags: shell, syntax

I have the following snippet I'm running from korn shell:

```
**clear
echo "Select your option"
PS3="Option?"
options=("Input new subsidy row" "Change subsidy id only" "Show subsidy row details" "Exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
            "Input new subsidy row")

                echo "Input new subsidy row"
            ;;
            "Change subsidy id only")
            echo "Change subsidy id only"
            ;;
            "Show subsidy row details")
            echo "Show subsidy row details"
            ;;
            "Exit")
            echo "Exit"
            ;;
            *) 
            echo "ERROR: Invalid selection"
            ;;
            esac
        done**
```

It works fine if I call it directly from the command line, but when I call at the end of another script I get the error:

syntax error at line 5 : `(' unexpected

Let me know if any of the preceding code is needed

thanks

Comment: Your interactive shell is probably bash.  The other script is a shell that does not support arrays, so `options=(...` is a syntax error.  Change the shebang of the script to be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: that's awesome, thank you!